# Parsing unknown POST Args in PHP

Tags: php, html

I have an HTML form being populated by a table of customer requests.  The user reviews each request, sets an operation, and submits.  The operation gets set into a post arg as follow

```
$postArray = array_keys($_POST);
```

[1]=>Keep [2]=>Reject [3]=>Reject [4]=>Ignore ["item id"]=>"operation"

This is how I am parsing my Post args... it seems awkward, the unused $idx.  I am new to PHP, is there a smoother way to do this?

```
$postArray = array_keys($_POST);            
foreach($postArray as $idx => $itemId) {            
    $operation = $_POST[$itemId];
    echo "$itemId $operation </br>";
    ...perform operation...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you may want to unset the 'item id' entry in your post array before you do the processing:

`unset($_POST['item id']);`

Then you can use foreach to loop over the key (idx) and value (operation).

```
foreach ($_POST as $idx => $operation)
{
    echo $idx . ' ' . $operation . '</br>';
    // perform operation.
}
```

The `array_keys` function was unnecessary because foreach can be used with associative arrays handling both their keys and values.

Answer (score 1):

You dont need to grab the the keys separately.

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {            
    echo "$key $value </br>";
}
```

Comment: My answer already covered this.  Adding another answer with the same information does not seem helpful.